# Permanent connections with Arduino Due

Tags: arduino-due

The Arduino Uno (for some models) has the ability to dislodge its IC chip. You can mount this on a piece of perfboard and, in essence, have a permanent connection. I will need the beefier Arduino Due, but I do not know how to make permanent connections with this device. Is there any way to form some kind of permanent connection with this board?

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong – there is no Arduino that can take its own chips off the board – but perhaps you meant to refer to Arduinos that have the chip in a socket.  Or maybe you are referring to the pin sockets along the edges of the boards.  In any case, you can buy little plastic cases to contain Unos, Dues, etc which may help hold pins into the pin sockets; or less elegantly, can hot-glue your wires in place

Comment: The AT91SAM3X8E is only available in QFP and BGA packages. Not in DIP like the UNO.

Comment: The chip on the Arduino Mega (ATmega1280) is available in DIP. So that might be an alternative, that's a bit more powerful then the UNO.

Comment: @Gerben Having more pins and more memory doesn't really equate to the chip being more powerful. It's still the same wimpy 8-bit core as the '328P. It just means you can be a little lazier with your programming and memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like you want is an Arduino Due footprint prototyping shield.

[Arduino make one](https://store.arduino.cc/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_code=A000080), although it is out of stock, but it gives you an idea of what you are looking for. There are plenty of other designs out there for purchase of varying degrees of complexity.

You solder the pins in place and mount it on top of your Due just like any shield, and solder your wires and components in where you want them.

An alternative option, of course, is to step away from Arduino and investigate some of the many other chips from other manufacturers out there that are considerably more powerful than the 8-bit ATMegas used on the low-end Arduinos, and yet are still available in a DIP footprint - chips like the PIC32MX1xx/2xx series from Microchip - 28 pin DIP (just like the 328P) yet 50MHz, 32-bit power.  Yes, it will be a bit of a learning curve, but there are helpful options out there that can assist you, like the [chipKIT](http://chipkit.net) system including the handy [DP32 board from Digilent](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?Prod=CHIPKIT-DP32).

Comment: Also investigate the [Teensy 3](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensy31.html) for a much beefier Arduino-compatible system with a small footprint which can be soldered to perfboard etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can disolder the female pin headers from pcb and make permanent connections on the remaining holes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you can do with this, is that you use temporary wires to connect and test the application and later, when you'll come to part, where you should "make-a-solid", you just solder these wires to the bottom, where pin headers are. I think this is the simplest way to do it.

If you want to do it a bit better, desolder female header pins and solder cables to those holes. It's more electronics-approved that way.

Or the simplest (but not the brighest): Jumper wires can be glued into female header pins, but I strongly unrecommend this option, as same as making a shield for this.

There's another(and most elegant too!) option of making a PCB version of arduino: Add the AtMega, few passive components and proper pads, to solder wires on.